# How to pass JavaScript variable in a function of onClick event of a dynamically generated link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to pass a JavaScript Variable in a function called redirect(),which will be invoked when a user clicks the link and that link is generated dynamically.
here is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function (){

        //this code will generate div when the page loads first time
        var n = 9;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = "d5";

    div.id=i+1;
  // alert(div.id);

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);

    $.ajax({ 
    async: false,                                      
      url: 'myapi.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var Name = data[2];
        var subdomain=data[15];
        var uniqueid=data[1];
        var shop_photo=data[3];
        var offer=data[19];              //get id
        //var vname = data[1];           //get name



       //$('#'+div.id).html("<a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com'>"+Name+"</a>"); 
       //$('#'+div.id).html("<img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/shop_image/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /><a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com'>"+Name+"</a><br>Special Offer<br><p>"+offer+"</p>");
       if(offer=="")
       {
           $('#'+div.id).html("<div class='div1'><img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/shop_image/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /></div><div class='div2'><a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com' onclick='redirect()'>"+Name+"</a></div></div>");
       }
       else
       {
           $('#'+div.id).html("<div class='div1'><img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/shop_image/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /></div><div class='div2'><a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com' onclick='redirect()>"+Name+"</a></div><div class='div3'>Special Offer<br class='br_special'>"+offer+"</div></div>");
       }





      } 



    });




}//this code will generate div when the page loads first time
```

i need to pass variable `var subdomain` in the function `redirect()`

and my function redirect() is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(a)
    {
        alert(a);//just for showing the passed variable I am using this alert();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your anchor tag, for example `<a id='id001' href='....'`
then do
    document.getElementById("id001").**addEventListener("click", function() {
    redirect(subdomain);});**

Answer (score 0):

just insert it to function call with correct type
for string type:

```
var html = "<a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com' onclick='redirect(\""+subdomain +"\")>"+Name+"</a>"
```

Comment: i used this:

var html="<a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com' onclick='redirect('"+subdomain +"')>"+Name+"</a>";
     $('#'+div.id).html("<div class='div1'><img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/shop_image/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /></div><div class='div2'>".html."</div></div>");

but I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
       $('#'+div.id).html("<div class='div1'><img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/shop_image/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /></div><div class='div2'><a href='http://www."+subdomain+".xyz.com' onclick='redirect("+ subdomain +")'>"+Name+"</a></div></div>");
```